# How to set an input textbox with the result from an ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Need to autopopulate firstname and last name textbox with results from ajax call. Here is aspx web form:

```
       <input id="firstName" type="text" size="26"  maxlength="20" name="firstName" tabindex="2" />                           
      <input id="lastName" type="text" value="" size="26" maxlength="20" name="lastName" tabindex="4" />
```

here is the jquery script with ajax call:

```
  <script>
    $("#lifeNumber").on('focusout', function (evt) {
        var options = {};
        options.url = "pcfform.aspx/GetEmployees";
        options.data = JSON.stringify({ lifeNumber: $(evt.target).val()  });
        options.type = "POST";
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.contentType = "application/json";
        options.success = function (result) {
           //need help here

            }
        };
        options.error = function (xhr, status, err) {
            alert(err);
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    });
</script>
```

Here is the WebMethod in aspx:

```
       public class Employee
       {
         public string FirstName { get; set; }
         public string LastName { get; set; }
       }

    [WebMethod]
    public static List<Employee> GetEmployees(string lifeNumber)
    {
        PCF.Entities.Data.Entities db = new PCF.Entities.Data.Entities();
        var data = db.MasterTables
                    .Where(x => x.Life_Hosp == lifeNumber)
                    .Select(x => new Employee
                    {
                        FirstName = x.FirstName,
                        LastName = x.LastName
                    });
        return data.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are struggling with the success method this code should help you:

```
$("#lifeNumber").on('focusout', function (evt) {
        var options = {};
        options.url = "pcfform.aspx/GetEmployees";
        options.data = JSON.stringify({ lifeNumber: $(evt.target).val()  });
        options.type = "POST";
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.contentType = "application/json";
        options.success = function (result) {


            $('#firstName').val(result.d[0].FirstName);
            $('#lastName').val(result.d[0].LastName);

            }
        };
        options.error = function (xhr, status, err) {
            alert(err);
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    });
```

Comment: Looks good but getting an error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data. Any ideas what is causing error?

Comment: The response `result` is already parsed probably, It's a parsed object not a string. Remove the first two line of the success method and use result instead of parsed_data. Ex: `$('#firstName').val(result.firstName);`

Comment: You are right it removes the error but it does not set the input box with the result . Here is the ajax response

Comment: {"d":[{"__type":"PCF.Pages.pcfform+Employee","FirstName":"CONSTANCE","LastName":"SIEGRIST"}]}

Comment: alert(result.FirstName) is undefined

Comment: $('#firstName').val(result.d[0].FirstName);
            $('#lastName').val(result.d[0].LastName); is the correct answer!